# Issue selecting collection properties using Mongoose mixed schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a project that involves creating pages from an external source. Since these external sources are variable in nature, I cannot strictly define a schema to use. So I did some research and learned about Mongoose's [Mixed schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) and created the following model:

```
var PageTemplate = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
);
```

During the import process, I perform an upsert operation to update existing entries and insert new ones:

```
PageTemplate
    .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            slug: page.slug
        },
        page,
        {
            upsert: true
        }
    );
```

Everything works great so far. The problem arises when I later try to fetch entries. When I `console.log` the entire object, I get what I expect--the entire object. For some reason, when I go to access a single property, I get `undefined`.

```
PageTemplate.findOne(
    {
        slug: slug
    },
    function(err, page) {
        console.log(page); // Prints entire object
        console.log(page.slug); // Undefined
    }
)
```

Have I misunderstood how mixed schemas are supposed to behave? Is there a commit operation I need to perform? For example, for a simple insert I would do:

```
var page = new PageTemplate(data);
page.save();
```

Any nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

*Note: My snippets have been simplified to demonstrate how I've set up my project. If more context is required, please let me know and I'll update my question.*

**Edit:** It may be noteworthy to add that this is only the case for properties not explicitly defined in the schema. If I define the schema with fields explicitly defined, I can access them correctly but this seems to defeat the purpose of a mixed type schema:

```
var PageTemplate = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        slug: String
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
);
```

Comment: What is being printed by `console.log(page)`?

Comment: @AndrewLavers: 

{
    _id: 553be4a36cdbaaf64690187a,
   slug: 'page-slug'
}

Comment: Ok, what if you `console.log(page.toObject())` ?

Comment: Same result. `typeof` also returns `object`.

Comment: Good! Then how about `console.log(page.toObject().slug)` ? :)

Comment: I don't understand why, but that works! If you could provide that solution as an answer, I will accept it. Perhaps some explanation as to why this might be happening as well? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you're getting back from `PageTemplate.findOne` is a Mongoose Document, which will only expose the fields you've defined in the schema.

You can call `page.toObject()` to convert the document into its raw javascript object equivalent in order to make all of your freeform schema fields accessible.

Also, to resolve some of the mystery, when you are `console.log`ing the mongoose document, the `.toString()` method is being invoked, which is essentially outputting the raw format.

Comment: Fantastic! Equal thanks for the solution and technical explanation. You've made me a better developer this day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `page.get('slug')`.

As far as I have validated [here](http://runnable.com/VTwQqLflyM0tFGSB/output), Mongoose [getter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get) also seems to work well with mixed type fields.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. However, Andrew's answer leaves me with a more robust solution for my scenario. I do appreciate you taking the time to supply an answer.

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh)